# Tradução do popup de medalha

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Falta traduzir isto:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

> How do you earn this badge?
>
> days asked
>
> positive question record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consertado. No ar no próximo build!

Comment: Alguma ideia melhor que "vá buscá-la" para o botão?

Comment: @bfavaretto nope... To absolutamente aberto à sugestões

Comment: *Vai que é sua, Taffarel!* :)

Comment: @bfavaretto essa ideia tem meu total apoio incondicional

Comment: @bfavaretto O meu também :D